# Sharing a folder on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.3: Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, samba, smb, nautilus

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.3 after sharing a folder from nautilus and not allowing guest access, accessing the share from windows (or Ubuntu itself!) results in a permission denied error. Worth mentioning that shares which guest access have been enabled for are accessible and working flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in order to allow a user to access the shares the following command must be performed first:

> sudo smbpasswd -a username

You will then be asked to enter a new password and afterwards you can access the share successfully from any other Windows/Ubuntu PC.